# How to fill in the blanks in a list in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm making a mastermind like application in Prolog, but I'm getting stuck at guessing the remainder of the solution.
I managed to do the first guess which is a list of 6 random colors. 
I want to tell Prolog the correct guesses and then it needs to try to fill in the blanks in that list with new colors.

```
color(green).
color(red).
color(blue).
color(purple).
color(yellow).
color(brown).
color(black).

guessedcorrect(Correct, Guess) :-
   Guess = Correct, 
   Guess = [S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6].

| ?- guessedcorrect([A, B, color(blue), D, E, F], Guess).

A = color(C)
B = color(G)
D = color(H)
E = color(I)
F = color(J)
Guess = [C,G,blue,H,I,J]
```

Why does it do this?
I expect it to give me a color for every variable and leave the blue as it is. for example.

```
Guess = [green, black, blue, blue, green, red]
```

Then i want to tell it which colors its guessed correctly.

```
guessedcorrect(A, black, blue, D, E, red).
```

I've tried to replace the variables by _ but it just gave me color(_) back.

Comment: `guessedcorrect/2` just unifies its arguments and ensure they have six elements. I don't understand how you can have the output you say you have. Also, you did not tell was is the behavior you expect to have.

Comment: I dont understand it either, I just added the expected behaviour.

Comment: The definition of `guessedcorrect` reports unused variables for S1, ..., S6. The line `| ?-` reports a syntax error, what is the `|` symbol doing here? Also if I enter the query `guessedcorrect([A, B, color(blue), D, E, F], Guess).` then none of the `X = color(Y)` is reported, just `Guess = [A, B, color(blue), D, E, F] .`. You won't have a good answer if your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Clocksin-Mellish' textbook had a mastermind example I used to test my Prolog interpreter.

From your question I cannot determine how far you are from coding a solution for this difficult puzzle (the program actually plays much better than me). So please consider this 'answer' for what is worth: almost nothing :)

Try

```
guessedcorrect(Correct, Guess) :-
   maplist(test_color, Correct),
   Guess = Correct.

test_color(color(C)) :- color(C).
```

and you get

```
?- guessedcorrect([A, B, color(blue), D, E, F], Guess).
A = B, B = D, D = E, E = F, F = color(green),
Guess = [color(green), color(green), color(blue), color(green), color(green), color(green)] ;
A = B, B = D, D = E, E = color(green),
F = color(red),
Guess = [color(green), color(green), color(blue), color(green), color(green), color(red)] 
...
```